# JQuery JSON getting nested value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I haven't dealt a lot with JSON strings in JavaScript and despite my research I can't figure my way around this simple problem.  Here is my issue:

My JSON `result`:

```
[{
    "Id": "7884",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "location": {
        "distance": 3.2988,
        "geoCode": {
            "latitude": "Y",
            "longitude": "X"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "14706 E Example Ave.",
            "state": "CA",
            "city": "Hollywood",
            "country": "USA",
            "postalCode": "99999"
        }
    }
}]
```

Now I parse and iterate  :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);

alert(obj[0].Id);
```

This works great for higher level parts of the string.

However I don't know how to get into the "address" section of the string.  I tried `obj[0].address.street`, `obj[0].address[street]` and even `obj[0].address[0]` to no avail.

Can someone direct me to the proper way to dig down to `street` level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass through `location` object since the `address` is inside it :

```
obj[0].location.address.street
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var obj =[{
    "Id": "7884",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "location": {
        "distance": 3.2988,
        "geoCode": {
            "latitude": "Y",
            "longitude": "X"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "14706 E Example Ave.",
            "state": "CA",
            "city": "Hollywood",
            "country": "USA",
            "postalCode": "99999"
        }
    }
}];

$('#result').text(obj[0].location.address.street);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='result'></span>
```

Comment: Oh dang!  I missed the "location" hierarchy!  Thanks Zakaria!

Comment: @Zak you can also access a property from a object that inherits from another object like this: `obj[0]['location']['address']['street']`.. this can also work to reference properties you don't know but use variables to refer the properties

Comment: Thanks @nosthertus for your intervention/suggestion and Yes it will work too.